# Can gradle use latest.release as default dependency version?

Tags: gradle

I want to write version: 'latest.release' somewhere in build.gradle once.
Then dependencies can be simplified like this:
  compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup'

just like spring boot does:
  compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, best practice is to always build against the exact version in order to avoid unpredicted scenarios.

However, if you really want to build against latest release, you can do it like this:

```
dependencies {
  myConfiguration 'group:module:latest.release'
}
```

The only (proper) way to enforce latest.release for all the artefacts is to write a resolution strategy.
Have a look at: [ResolutionStrategy](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally I add all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                eachDependency { d ->
                    if (!d.target.version)
                        d.useVersion 'latest.release'
                }
            }
        }  to configurations

Answer (score 0):

I would generally not use the absolute latest release, but you can do it simply in gradle.

The syntax is using "+" to match any version, e.g. "4.+" will check for the latest 4.anything version. If you just use "+" on its own, it finds the latest release version, but you will probably have troubles if you rely on this, as there are usually breaking changes over major versions, and your build will just download them without concern.

Anyway, a small test is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "junit:junit:+"
    }
}

import org.junit.Assert
task someTask << {
    Assert.assertEquals(true, !false)
}
```

Run this with

```
gradle someTask
```

Comment: + will try to get the latest (highest) available version, but this doesn't necessarily mean it's a release.

Comment: completely agree. of course this also depends on your definition of 'release', e.g. "latest beta release". however I agree, if the OP was after production releases and not alpha or beta, then as you suggested, use specific versions (which is what i also insist on internally - don't want builds failing because of external changes)